# "Thank you for having me be glad on how things turned out" validity

Tags: phrases

I'm writing a thank you note to a friend. The format is to have "thank you for" then a long list of *brief* things I'm thankful to them for. For example:

> Thank you for
>
> being a good friend
>
> making me feel comfortable
>
> having me glad on how things turned out

I'm not sure about the last one. The idea is supposed to sound similar to the phrase "I'm glad how things turned out in the end," but it just doesn't sound right. It's supposed to mean that I'm glad everything (including the bad) happened prior to me meeting them, as I may not have met them otherwise due to cause and effect. Some alternatives I've thought of:

> Thank you for causing me to be glad on how things turned out
>
> Thank you for making me glad on how things turned out

I'm hesistant about using these ones because saying they "*made* me" sounds like it was their intention to do so

Comment: "having me glad" is definitely not idiomatic. Your first alternative is grammatical, but sounds very stilted to me.

Comment: "Thank you for making it all worthwhile" "Thank you for making the shit bearable" Anything closer to what you say - "Thank you for making me happy that fate brought us together" - sounds incredibly awkward and pretty tenuous (it's good as thanking someone for something they had nothing to do with). It might be better just to finish the "Thank yous" and start a new sentence along the lines of "Life was shit until we met." Not posting an answer because I don't think this is really on-topic.

Comment: How does someone have me be glad, actually? Showing me the bright side of my situation? That would be encouraging and give me comfort, but not *have me be* a feeling.

Comment: @StuartF I like the word "worthwhile." I think I may settle on, "thank you for reminding me things can always be worthwhile."

Answer (score 1):

The reason it sounds odd is because you'd expect a verbal where you have "glad", an adjective. This is illustrated by your two alternatives "causing" and "making".
Perhaps something like:

> Thank you for the gladness I feel that things turned out well)

I'm not sure about the "well" at the end. It depends on your intent, and to be honest even here "gladness" is not a word you'd hear in that context often. Perhaps you'd more likely use "Thank you for the joy.." or "Thank you for the pleasure..." or "thank you for the happiness..."

It isn't super clear what you are trying to say, but you might consider these alternatives or variations of them.

In regards to the options you offered:

> Thank you for causing me to be glad on how things turned out

I'm not sure "on" is the right preposition here. Perhaps "about" would be better. Or you might consider "concerning" or "regarding" as alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider turning things around a bit:

> I’m so glad things turned out the way they did. Thank you for being a good friend and making me feel comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're thanking someone for an effect, rather than for their part in creating the effect.

You are glad that things worked out, but some might object that they didn't 'make' you glad - unless, for example, they adjusted your seratonin levels or interacted with your amygdala. They might instead have authorised a larger room, lower costs, greater publicity, etc, and your gladness was a response to things working out well.

To make the sentence flow better, match "thank you" with the thing you are thanking them for. Your feelings can be added as a comment after thanking them. For example:

- Thank you for coordinating with the suppliers. I'm glad everything worked out well.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'm no native.

All answers and comments considered, though, and with an intent to interfere as little as possible with your original sentence, here's my two cents:

*Thank you for giving me a reason to be glad about how things turned out.*

I believe this sorts out any logical gaps pointed out by the esteemed users above/below.

Btw, *"glad on"* sounds weird to my ears, but as I've already mentioned, they are the ears of a non-native...